# JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to unmarshall a class without knowing it's type (`JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz)`) , or what is proper way to test what is comming?
I do get messages for unmarshaling from plain text - String

Incomming classes doesn't implement any interface and can be in any package.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. The JAXB context needs *some* information about what classes should be bound to.  if necessary, pass a list of every possible JAXB-annotated class to the context factory method.

This shouldn't be a limitation, though - your own code also needs to know what classes to expect.  If your code doesn't know or care about the type of the bound classes, then JAXB isn't the tool for the job, you should just be unmarshalling into a generic DOM of some kind.

Comment: yes you are right, and I can unmarshall it via Unmarshaller.unmarshal(InputStream) finally without specifying class type right?

Comment: @fafaano: Correct. You probably still need to cast the result to something, though, otherwise why bother with JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate your classes, which can come in xml in one package and then pass the list of it to JAXBContext.